# Spin-Down not working on WD-Red

Tags: hard-drive, standby, hdparm, idle

I am using a WD Red drive

```
Model Family:     Western Digital Red
Device Model:     WDC WD120EMFZ-11A6JA0
```

I have set it to spin down after 10 minutes:

```
 hdparm -S 120 /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
 setting standby to 120 (10 minutes)
```

Unfortunately, it does not go standby.
To ensure that nothing is accessing the drive, I have not mounted it.

Then, I tested lower values for hdparm -S and found that it works up to a value of 24 (2 minutes). I also tested larger values up to 40, but no success.

I tested those values for APM_level=1 and APM_level=255.

Using hd-idle, I was able to make the drives spin down, but that came at the price of errors like this one:

```
[Sa Aug 20 12:27:04 2022] ata2: EH complete
[Sa Aug 20 12:27:09 2022] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
[Sa Aug 20 12:27:09 2022] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x800 SErr 0x850000 action 0x6 frozen
[Sa Aug 20 12:27:09 2022] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[Sa Aug 20 12:27:09 2022] ata2: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake LinkSeq }
[Sa Aug 20 12:27:09 2022] ata2.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Sa Aug 20 12:27:09 2022] ata2.00: cmd 60/20:58:20:aa:ef/00:00:33:03:00/40 tag 11 ncq dma 16384 in
[Sa Aug 20 12:27:09 2022] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[Sa Aug 20 12:27:09 2022] ata2: hard resetting link
[Sa Aug 20 12:27:09 2022] ata2: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
```

I could confirm that these issues were not related to bad SATA cables as google indicates but that they come and go depending on hd-idle activated or not.

Any Ideas how I could make the disk spin down after 10 minutes? 2 min seems a bit low to me.

Best regards,
Hendrik

Edit: I tested now values up to 120 (10 min) and it works only up to 24 (2 min)

For reference the script that I used to test the values between 20 and 40:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
do
hdparm -S $i /dev/sdc
time timeout --preserve-status --foreground 660s watch -n 10 -g  hdparm -C /dev/sdc
done
```

Comment: This discussion may help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/196473/setting-sata-hdd-spindown-time-for-western-digital-green-drives

Comment: Unfortunately not; it only proposes hd-idle in the end and that has other issues (see above)

Answer (score 1):

WD seems to have implemented `hdparm -S` in a non-standard way.

The article
[Spinning down a WD20EARS “Green” drive](https://sandeen.net/wordpress/computers/spinning-down-a-wd20ears/)
may also apply to your "Red" disk:

> Mostly through trial and error, I found out that **if you set a lower spindown timeout, i.e. hdparm -S 3, the drive will spin down in 10 minutes**.  So unlike most drives which follow the timeouts as specified in the hdparm manpage, this one seems to spin down in 10 minutes for low -S values, and never for higher values.  I don’t know what the threshold is, but for now, hdparm -S 3 is doing the trick for me.  After doing this, the drives finally managed to be idle most of the time, when not serving up media:
>
> [image]
>
> I also used the [idle3-tools](https://idle3-tools.sourceforge.net/) to
> turn off the idle3 behavior and save the drives from the massive
> load/unload cycles; I don’t know if that’s warranted or not, but I did
> it anyway.

Check if the above applies also to your disk. You might need to find out
the right `-S` parameter by trial and error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, that is exactly what I did (trial and error for values between 1 and 120. And for Values >24 it does not work. Opposed to the article you link above, up to a value of 24, the drive behaves according to spec. But that means that 10 min timeout seems not possible.

Comment: The WD firmware has a different behavior for your disk than in the above article, but is still non-standard. You could try to update the firmware from the [WD Red Dashboard](https://support-en.wd.com/app/products/product-detailweb/p/288#WD_downloads). If that doesn't help, I think that the most you can do is use the highest value possible, and of course also complain to WD Support.